# The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated.(535 5.7.3)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtp, office365

I am totally fed-up with Office 365 SMTP configuration, I have done all requirements to send email using my account on Office 365, and always giving me the same error message :

> The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not
> authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.57 Client not
> authenticated to send mail. Error: 535 5.7.3 Authentication
> unsuccessful [DX0P273CA0007.AREP273.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM
> 2023-06-01T20:34:23.527Z 08DB62D998FCDD7E]

- I have used direct password and did not work
- Used App password and activating the MFA and did not work.

the below code is used for sending the email which I don't think it has any issue

```
 SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.office365.com", 587);
        smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
        smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("hajjaj@alhajjaji.com", "*******");

        // Set up the email message
        MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
        mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("hajjaj@alhajjaji.com");
        mailMessage.To.Add("hajjaj@gmail.com");
        mailMessage.Subject = EmailSubject;
        mailMessage.Body = EmailMsg;
        mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
        smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
```

Application password is added as you can see
[image]

SMTP is enabled for that Mailbox also
[image]

SMTP Disabled status : not disabled
[image]
any help will be very apricated.
thanks

Comment: What version of Windows and .NET, exact build numbers please? And can you get a Wireshark trace on the connection attempt to see what the Server Hello and Client Hello look like. The password is irrelevant here, it's not even getting the TLS connection up.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Office 365 - "535: 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68538498/office-365-535-5-7-3-authentication-unsuccessful)

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev I have seen that answer and follow the answers steps which is in thins link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/authenticated-client-smtp-submission

Comment: @Charlieface The .NET Framework is 4.7.2 , I have tried both password , account password which was not accepted to use it and we had to create Application password to use it and had the same issue :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **smtp.office365.com** to work, you need to do the following:

1. Login into the Microsoft 365 Admin Center as an admin user.
2. Click Azure Active Directory in the menu. If the option is not visible, click Show All. See image #1.
3. In the **Azure Active Directory**, click **Properties** on the page. See Image #2
4. At the bottom of the page, click **Manage security defaults**.
5. Turn it off and answer why you are turing it off, then click Save. # See image #3
6. Test your email code.

Image #1
[image]

Image #2
[image]

[image]

BTW, make sure you are using .NET Framework 4.8 or later and user's office 365 MFA option is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the SMTP authentication of your Office 365 account hasn't been enabled. The third-party application uses SMTP submission to authenticate Office 365 account. To enable the SMTP auth, you can refer to the [Enable or disable authenticated client SMTP submission (SMTP AUTH) in Exchange Online](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/authenticated-client-smtp-submission) article.

Comment: no it is enabled please check the updates images on my question